# What's the opposite of damping?

Tags: functions, terminology

A colleague asked me this question and I had no clue.

> When a function (for instance, a sine wave) is multiplied by a decaying exponential, we call the phenomenon *damping*.  What would it be called if the wave is multiplied by a *growing* exponential?

I suggested *forcing* or *driving*, since functions of that form arise in simple harmonic oscillators driven by sine waves with frequency equal to the oscillator's frequency.  But I wondered if others had words for it.

Comment: "Negative damping" or "positive feedback" are common.

Comment: Driven/driving is certainly the term I've heard; see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Driven_harmonic_oscillators) for example.

Comment: Another possibility is "resonance". But in general the terminology would depends on "what caused the exponential growing mode" in the first place. It may be that [your friend is Merlin in disguise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Once_and_Future_King).

Comment: People (at least in electrical engineering) use amplification (=gain) as the opposite of damping (=loss)...

Comment: Driven is fine, but depending on the situation "resonance disaster" comes to mind, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call reinforcing and amplifying a signal positive feedback, and where you have neither dampening nor feedback I would call that resonance or ringing.

Answer (score 2):

In physics, it is indeed called forcing or driving. For example, the solutions to a spring problem satisfy the spring equation (the solutions are sines). If you apply an external force to the object attached to the spring, depending on the nature of the force, it can have a driving effect on the object. If you for example apply a sinusoidal, periodic force with the same frequency as the characteristic frequency of the spring system, you shall see that the solution will grow in magnitude for increasing $t$.

Comment: I disagree. In the typical spring-mass-damper, $m\ddot{x} + c\dot{x}+kx = F(x,t)$, the "forcing" term is $F(x,t)$, but the damping coefficient term is $c$. Changing signs on $c$ such that the damping effect is reversed is not the same as adding a forcing function.

Comment: You are right, I was trying to explain it in physical terms and in mechanical systems negative damping does not exist so you have to resort to some sort of external driving force. If you managed to apply a driving force $F(x,t) = k \dot{x}$ $k > c$ then the effective damping would be negative but I am not sure if you can realize that.

Answer (score 0):

isn't "amplification" more appropriate?